# How can i deal with "'Program.D(int)': not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#

I'm a novice coder, learning c# via a youtube video.
I cant figure out where am I wrong

Also sorry for bad English
Error message: `'Program.D(int)': not all code paths return a value`

Code:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace Rextester

{
    public class Program

    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            Console.WriteLine(D(0));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static string D (int DayNum)

        {
            string DayName;
            
            switch (DayNum)
            {
                case 0 :
                    DayName = "Sunday";
                    break;
                case 1 :
                    DayName = "Monday";
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    DayName = "Tuesday";
                    break;
                default :
                    DayName = "nah";
                
                    
            return DayName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ill receive any questions and answers, Thanks
BTW this is the first time i use stackoverflow so sorry

Comment: you only return in `default` case ... prolly typo

Answer (score 1):

You need to move `return DayName;` out of your switch statement.

Currently it's technically part of the `default` case, even though your indentation and line breaks doesn't make it look so. So only in the `default` case you do the `return`.

You could also just refactor the whole method to return in each case to be more clean and harmonious. E.g.:

```
static string D (int DayNum)
{       
    switch (DayNum)
    {
        case 0 :
            return "Sunday";
        case 1 :
            return "Monday";
        case 2 :
            return "Tuesday";
        default :
            return "nah";
    }
}
```